# How to hide server-side rendered HTML code in client-side

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm starting a project with Angular 7 and I was wondering whats the best way to hide "protected" HTML elements from users, based on permissions. I know the easiest way is to use a library like CASL to handle them, but I want true permission/role access check.

If the user shouldn't see a button, it must not be rendered at all, I know about ngIf and ngShow, even though it won't get to the HTML, it will be present in the minified bundle.js.

My approach was to do some tests with Angular Universal and using the isPlatformBrowser and isPlatformServer, but I found out that even if I use something like the following, the code will still be present in the bundle when Angular bootstraps in the client:

`<ng-container *ngIf="isPlatformServerFunction() && hasAccess()">
 <button> Secret Button </button>
<ng-container>`

**¿Is there a way to render something exclusively server-side and dont let the HTML/JS slip into the front-end when it's bootstraped after the server-side rendering?**

I wonder how this is handled in big applications like Facebook for example, because everyone says that it should be in the front-end, since the back-end APIs is secure, so if they get to the UI, they won't get to the API's data anyways, but I don't see admin buttons/code in Facebook's public bundle.

Comment: why not evaluate the code server side and not even let it reach the client ?

Comment: well in sites like facebook everyone has a token that contains all their access rights (and is stored in backend) without which you cant do anything at all including admin requests so in your case lets assume you are doing some request with credentials (cause why not) then you would create a backend interface that more or less jsut passes the request though but adds the credentials which can only be called if your authorized to call that interface by token .

Comment: more info on the token system (preferably use 3rd party systems for that) basically you have a login request to the backend which generates a random token or encoded details without any secure credentials and saves the userinformation that go with that token in the database (preferably with timestamp) then gives that token to the frontend now when a user tries to access that interface you check wether he passed you a token nad also check if it exists in the database and is connected to a user with the neccessary rights (and if it is within a time range) and then send the request

Comment: always remember anything that you are 'hiding' in front end code can be reproduced  by simple console inputs in the developer console and a little help of the network logging feature

Comment: Thank you for your insights and for sharing your knowledge on security and Facebook. The idea is actually not to let the code reach the client, but let the server render it and don't let it slip to the JS bundle, this is easy in PHP if you may, because you decide to render or not based on a simple condition, but in SPAs is not so easy, because there is a bundle being created and sent. On the SPA + SSR side, if you want the same effect, then maybe I should erase the JS Angular function in the bundle, but this should be done in runtime, according to the user role, that's the complexity here

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to render something exclusively server-side and dont let the HTML/JS slip into the front-end when it's bootstraped after the server-side rendering

Yes.

You have to build two distinct builds of your Angular project. One that contains *private* content and another that is *public*. This can be done by defining multiple environments for your Angular project.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8

You can define fake proxy services in your front-end build, but use the server-side providers to declare only services that exist only on the server. This prevents the source code from getting into the bundles.

```
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule,
  providers: [
    ServerService
  ]
}));
```

You then need to create a `server.ts` that selects which build to *bootstrap* depending upon a *security* check. How you perform this check, if you use cookies or whatever is purely a different question.

This is done by bootstrapping the Angular server-side rendering *per request* instead of the `app.engine()`.

https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine#advanced-usage

```
app.get('/**/*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.render('../dist/index', {
    req,
    res,
    bootstrap: OtherServerAppModule,
    providers: [
      OtherServerService
    ]
  });
});
```

It is in this block of code that you add the *logic* of which build to bootstrap.

The pieces of the puzzle are there to achieve the security you want. I can't provide a full tutorial on exactly how to do it, but I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think this is a good approach in case you have binary private or public content but, what if the private content changes based on the rol/permissions? (I know how to do the authentication/authorization server-side) It should be dynamic and done in runtime, unless you create say 10 different bundles for every user role. The goal is to use the ngIf directive, checking for permissions over a component for example and if he doesn't have permission, don't render the HTML but also don't send the JS to the bundle either. Is that possible with SSR and Angular as SPA?